# How to block DNS request from inside host with ASA 5505

Tags: domain-name-system, cisco-asa

This seemed simple enough but I have to be missing something. I have the following config to block all DNS request from the inside that are not going to the allowed external DNS server.

```
access-list INSIDE-ACCESS-OUT extended permit udp any object open-dns1 eq domain
access-list INSIDE-ACCESS-OUT extended permit udp any object open-dns2 eq domain
access-list INSIDE-ACCESS-OUT extended permit tcp any object open-dns1 eq domain
access-list INSIDE-ACCESS-OUT extended permit tcp any object open-dns2 eq domain
access-list INSIDE-ACCESS-OUT extended deny udp any any eq domain
access-list INSIDE-ACCESS-OUT extended deny tcp any any eq domain
access-list INSIDE-ACCESS-OUT extended permit ip any any

access-group INSIDE-ACCESS-OUT out interface inside
```

DNS can still get out to any server and packet tracer doesn't show the ACL being hit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ACL is applied backwards. You're applying it to packets going out the inside interface (From the internet to your internal hosts). This should fix it:

```
no access-group INSIDE-ACCESS-OUT out interface inside
access-group INSIDE-ACCESS-OUT in interface inside
```